# Logic-Provide a formal proof (A ∨ B) ∨ C , A → E , B ↔ E , C → E ⊢ E

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

Prove (AvB)vC,A->E, B<->E,C->E|=E

My work so far: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tuttw.png)

1.) (AvB)vC :PR

2.) A>E :PR

3.) B<->E :PR

4.) C>E :PR

5.)   A:AS

6.)   E:->E2,5

7.)   --

8.)   B:AS

9.)   E:<->E3,8

10.)  --

11.)   C:AS

12.)   E:->E4,11

13.)E:vE1,5-6,8-9,11-12

If possible, can some provide an explanation as to why my conclusion is false for this proof. Thank you.

Comment: Your phrasing makes it seem someone read your attempt and marked it as wrong. You should mention that somewhere, also whether an explanation of why wrong was given.

Comment: Please do not link to external images as an essential part of the post. Also please use proper formatting (mathjax)

Comment: The proof beeds two nested Disjunction Elim.